# Python Tkinter - add border color in grid cells

Tags: python, tkinter, border

i search how to have a colored border in grid cells and for this i used the frame color  in order to draw the white lines of the "table" but the strings inside the cells haven't the same legnth so the remain area is white instead of grey that i would like to have.

Here is a screenshot 
https://lut.im/DLzcIlu9/fXCvqOdk

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.fr/41081

Comment: please don't put your code in pastebin. Write just enough code to illustrate the problem, and include it in the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sticky="nsew"` so that the labels fill the space allocated to them. If you want the text to appear left-aligned, you will also have to add `anchor="w"` when creating the labels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works, but if it is possible i'd like to make it also left aligned to avoid being as a "Christmass tree". But if it is not possible i will keep aligned on the center.

Comment: @Dim971: labels have an `anchor` option which controls where the text is anchored. Use `anchor="w"` to have the text anchored to the west side of the widget.